# AWS: Onboarding on premise instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

Is there a way to onboard the Raspberrypi device in AWS. So that the same device can be managed using ec2 console and it can seamlessly work with the rest of AWS services?

I am just an experimental user, I don't need much heavy computer but use AWS to host my website and blogs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS console is for managing AWS resources, which, arguably, your Raspberry Pi is not.

Some services can work with non-AWS resources. For example you can install *System manager agent* (though not sure if there is a RPi version) on on-prem servers.

Alternatively you can install [**AWS Greengrass for Raspberry Pi**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/setup-filter.rpi.html) that gives it *some* AWS capabilities.

Hope that helps :)